# Does mysql_exporter have to be installed in each database container?

Tags: containers, prometheus, grafana, lxc

I'm using LXC for running mysql and put database, I have like 12 containers that contain databases, my monitoring tools are Grafana and mysql_exporter, can I only install mysql_exporter in one container, but still be able to include all database ip from different containers?

I have tried to make a user that can access the databse from the other container, but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a single mysql_exporter to gather metrics from multiple MySQL instances. Example of configuration provided in mysql_exporter's [documentation](https://github.com/prometheus/mysqld_exporter#multi-target-support).

You will have to create a user in every database with sufficient privileges, and provide these credentials in configuration at mysql_exporter location (`config.my-cnf` in the documentation)